# Opencv hit and miss behavior

Tags: python, opencv

I am running a morphological hit and miss with the kernel center element set to 0 (don't care):

```
cv2.morphologyEx(np.asarray([[0, 255, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 255, 0]], dtype=np.uint8), cv2.MORPH_HITMISS, np.asarray([[0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]], dtype=np.int8))
```

I am getting:
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]

While I am expecting to get:
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 255, 0], [0, 0, 0]]

Please explain this behavior.

Comment: I didn't even know this was implemented in OpenCV. Cool. There's definitely unexpected behavior though. I changed your kernel to `[[0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, -1]]` and got the correct flip.

Comment: yeah i know. the issue is when there are no -1. see the bug i filed below

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds There's a [conditional](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/morph.cpp#L2060) that handles the case when the [second structuring element](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/db/d06/tutorial_hitOrMiss.html) is all zeros, and they shortcut to using the input image instead of the complement. Should be a simple fix, just moving L2064-2065 before that `if`.

Answer (score 1):

i think this is a bug in opencv. i filed: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/8957